# Want to do: "for x in `ls`; do cd $x ; get.exp $x ; cd .. ; done" but in my EXPECT script

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

Basically just like the title says...

I want to ls the directory that I'm currently running my script in, and for every folder in the directory, cd into that directory and execute my script using the folder name as the argument.

ie: In `${HOME}` I have 2 directories say '31' and '32' (will always be numerical and incremental like that)

So, in my script I'm going to cd in 31, rsync some files into that directory from another machine, cd .., then cd into 32 and repeat till there are no more folders.

I have everything working with my current get.exp and running:

```
for x in ls; do cd $x ; get.exp $x ; cd .. ; done
```

as a bash alias. But I'd love to cut out the alias...

Comment: Shell note: [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- use `for x in *; ...`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! For the lazy, here's why: 

_The ls(1) command is pretty good at showing you the attributes of a single file (at least in some cases), but when you ask it for a list of files, there's a huge problem: Unix allows almost any character in a filename, including whitespace, newlines, commas, pipe symbols, and pretty much anything else you'd ever try to use as a delimiter except NUL._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tcl equivalent of your loop is

```
foreach x [glob -nocomplain *] {
    cd $x
    exec get.exp $x
    cd ..
}
```

You might be able to simplify that (perhaps just using `source get.exp` or calling the appropriate proc) but it's the same basic idea.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed. Instead of `exec get.exp $x` I just changed it to use my function `proc copyFiles {x}` (Since this is all in my get.exp script)